# How can I find all the years a Customer didn't make a Sale in a given Date range?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two related tables in my DB, let's suppose they're Customer and Sale, like shown below:

**Customer

PK CustomerID


CustomerName


CustomerBirthday**

and

**Sale

PK SaleId


FK CustomerId


SaleYear


SalePrice**

I would like to make a SELECT statement in the SQL Developer that returns all the years a Customer a didn't make a Sale and show all these years.
I tried something this:
br>

```
SELECT CustomerName, SalePrice, LISTAGG(TRIM(SaleYear), ', ' WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SaleYear), '\d{4}+)(\,\s?\1){1,}', '\1') AS YEARS_WITHOUT_SALE
FROM CUSTOMER
LEFT JOIN SALE ON CUSTOMER.CustomerID = SALE.CustomerID
WHERE NOT EXSISTS (
    SELECT * FROM SALE
    WHERE CUSTOMER.CustomerID = SALE.CustomerId
    AND SaleYear >= 2015
    AND SaleYear <= 2020
);
```

I had to create a regex to replace all the repeated year values I was getting, so just ignore it.


The code I made seems to be working, but I am getting years from a Sale that a Customer didn't make a sale in fact, like 2016. But there are cases where the Customer didn't make a sale in 2015 to 2020 range and there's no relation between Sale and Customer and I would like to show all the years of this range, like 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020. 


There are another cases where a Customer didn't make a sale between 2015 and 2020, but he made a sale  in 2016, therefore 2016 is shown. It's showed because there is a Sale related to that Customer,  but in my BD model it is logically deleted. 


But in the cases where there are no relation between the two tables, it means a Customer has never make a Sale, then I must show all the years in the given range and I think it's not workin properly.


I'm sorry if my explanation wasn't clear enough. I hope you understand my problem and give me some tips to find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a list of sales.  Let me assume the years are in `sales`.  Then use a `cross join` to generate all combinations -- and some mechanism to filter out the ones that exist:

```
select c.customerid, y.salesyear
from customers c cross join
     (select distinct salesyear from sales) y left join
     sales s
     on s.salesyear = y.salesyear and s.customerid = c.customerid
where s.customerid is null;
```

If you want a specific range of years, it might be more performance to include those as a derived table:

```
select c.customerid, y.salesyear
from customers c cross join
     (select 2015 as salesyear from dual union all
      select 2016 as salesyear from dual union all
      select 2017 as salesyear from dual union all
      select 2018 as salesyear from dual union all
      select 2019 as salesyear from dual 
     ) y
     sales s
     on s.salesyear = y.salesyear and s.customerid = c.customerid
where s.customerid is null;
```

Comment: I followed your first example and I made some modifications to achieve my goal and it worked! 
As metioned above, I have some Sales related to a Customer, then instead of only use where s.customerid is null i used where (s.customerid is null OR (s.customerid = c.customerid AND s.deleted = 1)) which brought me the right result.

Thank you so much!!!